# how to make a list from result of a function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, list, xlsxwriter

When I run my code it works very well and makes an excel file I named exel.xlsx, but there is no information in exel.xlsx.

I think I make a mistake in making a list but I can't find a solution.

```
def randStr(length=7):
    characters = list('bcdghijkmnpqrtuvwxyz23456789')
    shuffle(characters)
    exel = ''.join(characters[:length])
    listb = [exel]
    listb.append(exel)
    workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('Exel.xlsx')
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet('randomise')
    chart = workbook.add_chart({'type': 'line'})
    expenses = (listb)
    row = 0
    col = 0
    workbook.close()
    return exel
```

Comment: Random string is written in `exel` or `listb`, but you don't seem to do anything with this information. It should be linked to `worksheet` or `chart`.

Comment: Does the resulting file have a worksheet called `randomise`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved!

```
def randStr(length=7):

    characters = list('bcdghijkmnpqrtuvwxyz23456789')
    shuffle(characters)
    listc=''.join(characters[:length])

    return listc

listb=[]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for i in range(20):
        value1=(randStr())
        listb.append(value1)
        workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('Exel.xlsx')
        worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet('randomise')
        worksheet.write_column(0,0,listb)
        chart = workbook.add_chart({'type': 'line'})
        expenses =(listb)
        row = 0
        col = 0
        workbook.close()
        img = makeImage(value1, width=512)
        with open('%d.png' % i, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(img)
        print (i)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('chart_line.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

# Add the worksheet data to be plotted.
data = [10, 40, 50, 20, 10, 50]
worksheet.write_column('A1', data)

# Create a new chart object.
chart = workbook.add_chart({'type': 'line'})

# Add a series to the chart.
chart.add_series({'values': '=Sheet1!$A$1:$A$6'})

# Insert the chart into the worksheet.
worksheet.insert_chart('C1', chart)

workbook.close()
```

This is the basic way to add_chart , then adding the values to chart and inserting the chart . 
But you are not adding any value to your chart. Moreover you are not adding any value to the column/row in sheet.
I ran your code , sheet with name "randomise" is created , but no data in it, as you havent added anything